# xUnit Runner for Visual Studio 2012 and native .dlls

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2012, xunit, xunit.net

### Context

I am an application with C# and C++/CLI dlls. The C++/CLI dlls reference pure C++ .dlls, e.g. the boost libraries.

Tests are compiled into Tests.dll, which is placed with all the other binaries in $(SolutionDir)\bin\Debug.

### Problem

Trying to run the xunit tests using Visual Studio 2012 fails, with the following error:

```
xUnit.net: Exception discovering tests from C:\Dev\xu-tests\bin\Debug\Tests.dll: 
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ManagedCpp.DLL' 
> or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
> File name: 'ManagedCpp.DLL'
```

I can reproduce the problem in two ways outside of visual studio:

- When trying to run the console runner from outside this directory

  ..(longpath)..\xunit.console.clr4.exe Debug\Tests.dll
- When trying to run the GUI runner from its installed directory.

I can get it to work however when I use the console to get to the bin\Debug directory, then start the console or GUI runner from there.

This makes me believe that the problem is that VS2012 tries to run the unit tests not using the bin\Debug directory as working directory.

### Question

How can I set the working directory in which xunit is run to $(OutDir) (or any specific directory)?